# Do acids stay acid forever?

Tags: acid-base

I mean their pH value never change unless we dilute with water etc?

> An acid is a molecule or ion capable of donating a proton (hydrogen
>   ion H+) (a Brønsted–Lowry acid), or, alternatively, capable of forming
>   a covalent bond with an electron pair.

So acids stay acids forever?

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/20039/do-chemicals-have-an-expiry-date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So acids stay acids forever?

You know a company markets that *diamonds are forever*. Well may be not, a diamond is not thermodynamically stable. It may wish to turn back into graphite if you somehow provide the right activation energy.

So there is nothing special about acids. Acids are like other molecules some may remain stable for a long time and some may not.

An example is that of sulfuric acid. If someone leaves concentrated acid in an open beaker, in period of few months its volume will increase. How? It absorbs moisture from air.

If you leave conc. HCl bottle open, HCl gas will escape into air and the acid concentration will decrease.

Moral of the story: Nothing is permanent but change.